# Quick access to control panel stuff in Vista

Tags: windows-vista, shortcut

Vista's control panel is more useless then ever.

One example:

I used to be able to access network devices with a couple clicks. From there I could check IP settings, disable, reset devices etc.

Now I have to click start, control panel, show classic view, double click network and sharing center, click "manage network connections".

We've probably all found ways to deal with it, but I did something that you might find useful.

The control panel settings are accessed through CPL files.

I did a search in c:\windows for all CPL files. 
I created a shortcut to each on a folder in my profile. (right click drag, create shortcut)
I deleted all the duplicates.
I ran them all one at a time and figured out what they did.
I renamed them to what function they accessed.
I deleted ones that didn't work or were not useful to me.

My list now:

- Add Remove Programs.lnk
- Bluetooth Detection.lnk
- Display Settings.lnk
- Firewall.lnk
- HardwareWizard.lnk
- Intel Wireless.lnk
- Internet Properties.lnk
- Mouse.lnk
- Network Properties.lnk
- NVIDIA.lnk
- Power.lnk
- SCCM Config.lnk
- SCCM Download Monitor.lnk
- SCCM Remote.lnk
- SCCM Run Adv.lnk
- Security Center.lnk
- Sound.lnk
- System Properties.lnk
- Time and Date.lnk

I then created taskbar toolbar pointing to that directory.

Now when I click Network Properties.lnk I get C:\Windows\System32\ncpa.cpl which takes me right to my network devices.

When I click "add remove programs" I get what Microsoft has burned into my brain for years, my installed programs list instead of having to remember that it's called "programs and features" now.

This works for more then just Vista.

Comment: This post is full of fail.  A real admin doesn't launch these from a gui, and typically not even from the machine!
 
http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/Windows2003/AdminTips/Admin/LaunchingControlPanelAppsfromtheCommandLine.html

Comment: ...says the 12-day member with 85 rep points and uses phrases like 'full of fail'

Comment: says the 12-day member with 85 rep points and uses phrases like 'full of fail' to the 10-day member with 754 rep points...just saying

Comment: Now guys, this isn't that type of neighborhood.  Yet.

Comment: If you dislike a question, downvoting is a great way to express yourself.  Minimizes on drama.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the start menu, hit properties. Start menu tab, hit Customize. In the list, select Display as menu for the Control Panel item. Ok and Ok.

Now all you need to do is click the start menu and then control panel - which will expand into an enormous context menu with all applets right there.

Don't forget to expose the admin tools in the root of the start menu as well...

As far as the network connections list (which I agree is annoyingly well-hidden in Vista), I think most have learned to simply run ncpa.cpl - just as we all just run mstsc, right? ^^

Comment: I have this set as well, but doesn't get you to the deeper parts like ncpa.cpl

Comment: I keep a couple of shortcuts for mstsc too. Console, full screen, etc along with dameware.